Is there a mathematical way to measure the randomness of a deterministic object?
Is there a mathematical way to measure the randomness of a deterministic object?
For instance, say I tell you one of the following sequences was randomly generated. I bet you can tell which one was it, despite them being equiprobable on their sample space.
$$
\color{magenta}{1111}
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}{0000}
\color{magenta}{11}
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}{111111}
\color{teal}{00}
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}{00}
\color{magenta}{1111}
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}{00000}
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}1
\\
\color{magenta}1
\color{teal}0
\color{magenta}{11}
\color{teal}{00}
\color{magenta}{111}
\color{teal}{000}
\color{magenta}{1111}
\color{teal}{0000}
\color{magenta}{11111}
\color{teal}{00000}
\color{magenta}{111111}
\color{teal}{000000}$$
In this sense, one of these sequences looks more random then the other. Of course, this has a simple explanation: one of these sequences follows a recognizable pattern. We don't expect patterns from random objects.
I'm not trying to formalize the intuitive notion of randomness (often called pseudorandomness), however. If there is a simple pattern, the object should not be considered random, even if the pattern is not easily recognizable, i.e., even if it looks random. What I expect is to differentiate between simple and complex patterns.
While pondering on this I started to think about the idea of entropy. I've been taught in my youth entropy is a measure of disorder, so, for instance, a pile of sand "has more entropy" than a sandcastle. This intuitive notion is the same as a sequence seeming random or not: the more disorderly, the more random it seems.
I later found this same idea made more formal. Say you want to describe a sequence. One way to do it is to describe each of its elements. If there is no pattern to it, this is, in fact, the only way to do it. Otherwise, if you tell me the pattern I can recover the sequence immediately. This motivates one possible mathematical definition:

Given a sequence $x = (x_n)_n$ and a programming language $P$, the entropy of $x$ with respect to $P$ is the length of the shortest piece of code in $P$ that computes the terms of $x$.

Does this definition makes sense? Is it useful? Has something like this already been proposed? It makes me uncomfortable seeing this has (apparently) nothing to do with the statistical notion of entropy (also called Shannon Entropy). Intuitively it seems to obey the expected laws of random sequences having high entropy in general and sequences that follow simple patterns having low entropy.

Well... is $110010001001111101010000001001$ random?  I got it by computing $\sin (1)=0.841470985$ and then dropping the decimal point and converting to binary.  So, a very simple algorithm.  I could artificially complicate it by composing a few functions, I suppose.  Would that make it random?   Better, perhaps, to speak of numbers generated by a randomizing algorithm (one that measures discharges from a capacitor or such).

you need a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and then you can take a property which you want to measure randomness: a random variable $X: \Omega \to \Omega'$ and ask what is the probability that $X$ has value $c$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X = c)$.

May be worth noting that the Halting problem interferes with naive attempts to define randomness.  For instance, you could try to say something like "a random binary string of length $n$ is one that can not be generated by a program (in some fixed Universal Turing Machine) of length $<f(n)$ for some specified function $f(n)$"  but, because of the Halting problem, this can't be deterministic.

"I bet you can tell which one was it, despite them being equiprobable on their sample space." - this sentence is self-contradictory to me...

From the practical perspective we simply test number generators through well designed tests like TestU01. The theoretical notion of randomness that you refer to here is of little practical use. In particular the "entropy" definition you proposed is of no importance, and likely extremely hard to calculate, if possible.

May be of interest: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/truly-random-number-generator-turing-computable  Alos, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test

It sounds like you might be looking for "Shannon entropy," a concept in information theory.

@DavidK I referred to Shannon entropy in my post. It doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for since it is defined over random variables.

@lulu A bounded halting problem is deterministically solvable, though extremely difficult. Whether a string can be generated by any program of length less than $M$ is computable. For example, an oracle program exists as a lookup into a table indexed by programs with all the actual behaviors as either an output result or non-terminating. Not that we know all the correct answers in interesting cases, but they exist.

You might want to revisit Shannon entropy. Yes, there is discussion of random variables there. But the motivation behind it is how many bits actually need to be transmitted in order to exactly reproduce a given string of bits at the other end of a communications channel. There you're dealing with a deterministic string (the message) and a deterministic encoding. And as noted in the first posted answer, it is related to Kolmogorov complexity.

@aschepler  By the "bounded" halting problem, you mean that we limit both the program length and the number of steps we allow the program to run?  Sure.  That's decidable.

@lulu No, I mean just program length, including any inputs. For a given maximum length $M$, there exists an oracle program taking a limited program as input which can correctly determine the result of that program. But except for trivially small $M$, I can neither write nor verify that oracle program. In the unbounded case, we know no such oracle program exists at all. Not much of a practical difference, but technically different.

You might also be interested in Martin-Löf randomness.

Getting at the question in your title, there definitely are a variety of statistical methods for comparing randomness. I don't know if this helps with what you're looking for in the post itself, but for your particular example, there are many statistical tools that could apply: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574333/how-can-i-determine-which-of-two-sequences-of-coin-flips-is-real-and-which-is-fa/574424#574424 For example, Moran's I shows your 1st is pretty random (0.02), while the 2nd is moderately clustered (0.46).

Obligatory xkcd.

One interesting metric is the complexity function (also called the block complexity function) of the sequence, which, given some length $n$, measures how many distinct substrings of length $n$ occur anywhere in the sequence. It doesn't guarantee 'random' behavior, since the Champernowne word (among others) has maximal block complexity. But lower bounds can be placed on the complexity functions of some pseudo-random sequences that otherwise resist analysis.

I think you may be satisfied with Kolmogorov complexity.
This is simply: pick a model of computation, such as “Turing machines” or “programs written in golang”. Then take the length of the shortest instance that computes your finite sequence. Strings that seem intuitively “less random” are those generated by smaller programs and which therefore have simpler descriptions.
It is, in fact, closely related to Shannon entropy.

Actually finding that shortest instance can be difficult, though.

@StigHemmer Finding the shortest instance is undecidable in general.

An interesting tidbit is that any two Turing-complete models of computation $A$ and $B$ have $\forall s : (|K_A(s) - K_B(s)| \leq c)$ for some constant $c$ dependent on $A, B$. So up to a constant it doesn't matter which model you choose (although for real-world inputs that constant may be significantly larger than the complexity of inputs you're interested in). Since both models are Turing-complete $c$ is essentially just the maximum size of the emulator to emulate $A$ on $B$ or vice versa.

Minimum size. ${}{}$

It seems worth noting that codegolf.SE has a dedicated tag.

While the Wald–Wolfowitz runs test does not directly "measure the randomness" of a binary sequence, I nevertheless feel it deserves a mention here:
The idea is to count the number of runs in the sequence, i.e. how often it changes from 0 to 1 and vice-versa.
If the elements of the sequence were chosen iid (they need not have the same probability of occurence), the  distribution of the number of runs is asymptotically normal and can be computed.
This distribution gives you a direct measure how probable the observed number of runs in the sequence is under the iid assumption.
Thus, using the test you can detect/measure the randomness of the runs in the sequence - which is of course only one aspect of the randomness. Nevertheless it's useful in practice since it can easily be computed.

Along these lines, I think one can also do something similar with the autocorrelation of the sequence but I don"t know the details.

This is in   many ways a more useful answer tha mine,  since as you say the runs can easily be computed, whereas the Kolmogorov complexity typically can't be computed at all.
